# how to delete a nested object within an array in mongoose and express?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
const pickupGameSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      id: String,
      userAdminFirst: String,
      userAdminLast: String,
      userAdminID: String,
      userAttending: [{
        id: String,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        address: String,
      }]
}
)
```

And a delete route that looks like this:

```
router.delete(':id/players/:playerId', async (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello');
  try {
    const result = await pickupGame.updateOne(
        { '_id': req.params.pickId, 'userAttending._id': req.params.playerId },
        {
          $pull: { 'userAttending': { _id: req.params.playerId } },
        },
    );
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
  }
},

);
```

I need my route to delete a specific user within the userAttending array. What is the best way to do this?